# Testbench error says I have array when I don't

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vivado

I'm trying to run an FSM and Adder in VHDL so that it acts as a vending machine, but I am getting some errors, The FSM Machine is supposed to pick up on how much money you put into the machine and the adder is supposed to add the states and end up giving you change. Vivado keeps thinking my code is an array and I don't know why, can anyone help me out?

I tried running it and changing a few things around but keep getting errors.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity vend is
    port(
    clock, reset, sensor, item: in std_logic;
    coin: in std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    change_done, item_done: out std_logic;
    change: out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
     A : in std_logic; 
     B : in std_logic;  
     Cin : in std_logic; 
     S : out std_logic; 
     Cout : out std_logic); 
end vend;

architecture Behavioral of vend is
type mealy_fsm is (rest, coin_in, in_1, in_2, coin_out, item_out);
signal current_state, next_state: MEALY_FSM;


begin
process(clock,reset)
begin
S <= A XOR B XOR Cin ; 
 Cout <= (A AND B) OR (Cin AND A) OR (Cin AND B) ; 

    if(reset = '0')then
        current_state <= rest;
    elsif(rising_edge(clock))then
        current_state <= next_state;
    end if;
end process;

process(current_state, coin)
begin
S <= A XOR B XOR Cin ; 
 Cout <= (A AND B) OR (Cin AND A) OR (Cin AND B) ; 
case current_state is
    when rest =>
    item_done <= '0';
    change <= "00";
    next_state <= coin_in;

    when coin_in =>
    if(coin = "00")then
    item_done <= '0';
    change <= "00";
    change_done <= '1';
    next_state <= coin_in;

    elsif(coin = "01")then
    item_done <= '0';
    change <= "00";
    change_done <= '1';
    next_state <= in_1;

    elsif(coin = "10")then
    item_done <= '0';
    change <= "00";
    change_done <= '1';
    next_state <= in_2;

    end if;

    S <= A XOR B XOR Cin ; 
     Cout <= (A AND B) OR (Cin AND A) OR (Cin AND B) ; 

    when in_1 =>
    if(item = '1')then
    item_done <= '1';
    change <= "00";
    change_done <= '1';
    next_state <= coin_out;

    elsif(coin = "00")then
    item_done <= '0';
    change <= "00";
    change_done <= '1';
    next_state <= in_1;

    elsif(coin = "01")then
    item_done <= '0';
    change <= "00";
    change_done <= '1';
    next_state <= in_2;

    end if;

    S <= A XOR B XOR Cin ; 
     Cout <= (A AND B) OR (Cin AND A) OR (Cin AND B) ; 

    when in_2 =>
    if(item = '1')then
    item_done <= '1';
    change <= "00";
    change_done <= '0';
    next_state <= coin_out;

    elsif(coin = "00")then
    item_done <= '0';
    change <= "00";
    change_done <= '1';
    next_state <= in_2;

    end if;
    end case;
    end process; 

    end Behavioral;
```

And the test bench:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY vend_tb IS
END vend_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF vend_tb IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Moore FSM Sequence Detector in VHDL

    COMPONENT vend
    PORT(
         clock : IN  std_logic;
         reset : IN  std_logic;
         sensor : IN  std_logic;
         coin : IN std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
         change: out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
         change_done : OUT  std_logic;
           A : in STD_LOGIC; 
          B : in STD_LOGIC;  
          Cin : in STD_LOGIC; 
          S : out STD_LOGIC; 
          Cout : out STD_LOGIC);
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal clock : std_logic := '0';
   signal reset : std_logic := '0';
   signal sensor : std_logic := '0';
   signal coin : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0) := "00";
   signal A : std_logic := '0'; 
   signal B : std_logic := '0'; 
   signal Cin : std_logic := '0'; 

  --Outputs
   signal change : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0) := "00";
   signal change_done : std_logic;
   signal S : std_logic; 
   signal Cout : std_logic; 

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clock_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN


   uut:  vend PORT MAP (
          clock => clock,
          reset => reset,
          coin => coin,
          sensor => sensor,
          change => change,
          change_done => change_done,
           A => A, 
           B => B, 
           Cin => Cin, 
           S => S, 
           Cout => Cout 
           ); 

   -- Clock process definitions
   clock_process :process
   begin
  clock <= '0';
  wait for clock_period/2;
  clock <= '1';
  wait for clock_period/2;
   end process;


   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin  
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
  sensor <= '0';
  reset <= '1';
  -- Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
  wait for 30 ns;
      reset <= '0';
  wait for 40 ns;
  sensor <= '1';
  wait for 10 ns;
  sensor <= '0';
  wait for 10 ns;
  sensor <= '1'; 
  wait for 20 ns;
  sensor <= '0'; 
  wait for 20 ns;
  sensor <= '1'; 
  wait for 20 ns;
  sensor <= '0'; 

   -- hold reset state for 100 ns. 

   wait for 100 ns;  

   -- insert stimulus here 

   A <= '1';  
   B <= '0'; 
   Cin <= '0';  
   wait for 10 ns; 

   A <= '0';  
   B <= '1'; 
   Cin <= '0';  
   wait for 10 ns; 

   A <= '0';  
   B <= '0'; 
   Cin <= '1';  
   wait for 10 ns; 

   A <= '0';  
   B <= '0'; 
   Cin <= '0';  
   wait for 10 ns; 
      -- insert stimulus here 
      wait;
   end process;
END;
```

My expected output should just be a simple signal, when I simulate the code just to see that the FSM and Adder work together without any issues.

Errors received:

`[VRFC 10-2335] case statement does not cover all choices. 'others' clause is needed [vend.vhd:39]`

`[VRFC 10-704] formal item has no actual or default value [vend.vhd:6]`

`[XSIM 43-3321] Static elaboration of top level VHDL design unit vend_tb in library work failed.`

Comment: Most of these errors show up in naive web searches. What research have you done? What debugging?

Answer (score 0):

The first message should be self-explanatory. Your type `mealy_fsm` includes `coin_out` and `item_out`, but your case statement using `current_state` (of type `mealy_fsm`) doesn't say what to do when `current_state` is in these states. Either add `coin_out` and `item_out` to your case statement, remove them from the type, or add an others clause as the message states.

I think your second error is telling you your uut contains an input `item`, but you don't map that in your testbench. Add `item` to your component declaration in the testbench and add it to your port map in the testbench. As user_007 points out, `item_done` is similarly missing.

I'm not sure why you think the tool believes your "code is an array".

Comment: 1. I wouldnt put an others in the state machine. Too easy to leave it empty and lock up your state machine in live use. The compiler is doing a useful job when you dont have others. 2. This acts as a good example as to why component declarations for VHDL are not recommended. Direct instantiation would have picked up this error at the syntax check.